# Toggle one list item at a time with React/TS functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, toggle

I have a simple component with a few nested bits of mark-up:

```
    import React, { ReactElement } from "react";

    type MenuItem = {
        title: string;
        subItems?: Array<string>;
    };

    type MenuConfig = Array<MenuItem>;

    function Item({ item }: { item: MenuItem }): ReactElement {
        const [showItem, setShowItem] = React.useState(false);
        const handleShowItem = (): void => {
            setShowItem(!showItem);
        };
        return (
            <>
                {item.subItems && (
                    <button onClick={() => handleShowItem()}>
                        {showItem ? "Hide" : "Expand"}
                    </button>
                )}
                {showItem && <SubItem item={item} />}
            </>
        );
    }

    function SubItem({ item }: { item: MenuItem }): ReactElement {
        const { title } = item;
        return (
            <ul>
                {item?.subItems?.map((subitem: string, i: number) => (
                    <li key={i}>
                        {subitem}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }

    function Solution({ menuConfig }: { menuConfig: MenuConfig }): ReactElement {
        return (
            <>
                {menuConfig.map((item: MenuItem, i: number) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <span>{item.title}</span>
                        <Item item={item} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </>
        );
    }

    export default Solution;
```

This is what I am passing in:

```
menuConfig={[
                {
                    title: "About",
                },
                {
                    title: "Prices",
                    subItems: ["Hosting", "Services"],
                },
                {
                    title: "Contact",
                    subItems: ["Email", "Mobile"],
                },
            ]}
```

Now, it functions as expected, if an item contains `subItems` then an `Expand` button will be show which, if clicked, will only expand the relevant list.

How should I go about making sure **only one list would be open at a time**, given my implementation?

So if the user clicks `Expand` on a button, the other previously expanded lists should close.

I can't mess with the data that's coming in, so can't add ids to the object, but titles are unique.

*I've searched and whilst there are a few examples, they don't help me, I just can't wrap my head around this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for React context. You essentially want a shared state among your menu. You can achieve this with prop drilling however contexts are a much cleaner solution.

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wozniak-5ls6qj?file=/src/App.tsx:731-1125)

```
const MenuContext = createContext<{
  expandedState?: [number, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>];
}>({});
```

```
function Solution(): ReactElement {
  const expandedState = useState<number>(null);
  const value = { expandedState };
  return (
    <>
      <MenuContext.Provider value={value}>
        {menuConfig.map((item: MenuItem, i: number) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <span>{item.title}</span>
            <Item i={i} item={item} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </MenuContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
function Item({ item, i }: { item: MenuItem; i: number }): ReactElement {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useContext(MenuContext)?.expandedState ?? [];
  const shown = expanded === i;
  return (
    <>
      {item.subItems && (
        <button onClick={() => setExpanded?.(i)}>
          {shown ? "Hide" : "Expand"}
        </button>
      )}
      {shown && <SubItem item={item} />}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to exemplify this for me. It makes sense. Any ideas why is it moaning in my IDE about the `[expanded, setExpanded]` var/setter declaration/assignment with `Type '[number, Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>] | undefined' is not an array type.ts(2461)`?

Comment: Yeah that happens to me as well, not sure why CSB doesn't complain. See updated answer specifically in the Item component

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Also had to do a non-null assertion operator here `const expandedState = useState<number>(null!);` as I had a `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | (() => number)'.ts(2345)`.

Comment: OK, you could also modify the generic type to `<number | null>` seems as even though CSB and vscode both use monaco editor they  have different type checking

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this can be a clear solution.

```
const [productData, setProductData] = useState();
const toggleButton = (id) => {
const newlist = productData.map((item) => {
  if(item._id === id){
    const updatedItem = {
      ...item,
      status: !item.status
    };
    return updatedItem;
  }
  return item;
});
setProductData(newlist);
}
```